# How to dynamically set distance length of connected nodes?

Tags: d3.js

Here I'm attempting to configure connected nodes so that the length of connecting line of each node is configured by dataset.

This is line where I set the length :

```
.linkDistance([dataset.edges[0].distance])
```

This sets all connected nodes line length to same value, but how to configure so that it reads current node distance parameter instead of setting all line lengths to `dataset.edges[0].distance` ?

I think need to loop through each of of distances dataset and apply to nodes ?

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7pvhxfzg/30/

src :

```
var w = 500;
var h = 300;
var dataset = {
    nodes:[
            {name:"Adam"},
            {name:"Bob"},
            {name:"Carrie"},
            {name:"Donovan"},
            {name:"Edward"},
            {name:"Felicity"},
            {name:"George"},
            {name:"Hannah"},
            {name:"Iris"},
            {name:"Jerry"}
    ],
    edges:[
            {source: 0, target: 1, distance: 200},
            {source: 0, target: 1, distance: 200},
            {source: 0, target: 3, distance: 200},
            {source: 0, target: 4, distance: 200},
            {source: 1, target: 5, distance: 200}
    ]
};
var force = d3.layout.force()
                        .nodes(dataset.nodes)
                        .links(dataset.edges)
                        .size([w, h])
                        .linkDistance([dataset.edges[0].distance])
                        .charge([-150])
                        .start();

var colors = d3.scale.category10();
var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);
var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
                .data(dataset.edges)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                .style("stroke-width", 5);
var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(dataset.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .style("fill", function(d, i){
                    return colors(i);
                })
                .call(force.drag);

var label = svg.selectAll(".mytext")
                .data(dataset.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("fill", "#555")
                .style("font-family", "Arial")
                .style("font-size", 12);



force.on("tick", function(){
    edges.attr("x1", function(d){ return d.source.x; })
         .attr("y1", function(d){ return d.source.y; })
         .attr("x2", function(d){ return d.target.x; })
         .attr("y2", function(d){ return d.target.y; });
    nodes.attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
         .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; });
    label.attr("x", function(d){ return d.x; })
         .attr("y", function (d) {return d.y - 10; });


});
```

Updated with answer :

```
var w = 500;
var h = 300;
var dataset = {
    nodes:[
            {name:"Adam"},
            {name:"Bob"},
            {name:"Carrie"},
            {name:"Donovan"},
            {name:"Edward"},
            {name:"Felicity"},
            {name:"George"},
            {name:"Hannah"},
            {name:"Iris"},
            {name:"Jerry"}
    ],
    edges:[
            {source: 0, target: 1, distance: 200},
            {source: 0, target: 1, distance: 200},
            {source: 0, target: 3, distance: 100},
            {source: 0, target: 4, distance: 200},
            {source: 1, target: 5, distance: 200}
    ]
};
var force = d3.layout.force()
                        .nodes(dataset.nodes)
                        .links(dataset.edges)
                        .size([w, h])
                        .linkDistance(function(link) { return link.distance })
                        .charge([-150])
                        .start();

var colors = d3.scale.category10();
var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);
var edges = svg.selectAll("line")
                .data(dataset.edges)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                .style("stroke-width", 5);
var nodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(dataset.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .style("fill", function(d, i){
                    return colors(i);
                })
                .call(force.drag);

var label = svg.selectAll(".mytext")
                .data(dataset.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("fill", "#555")
                .style("font-family", "Arial")
                .style("font-size", 12);



force.on("tick", function(){
    edges.attr("x1", function(d){ return d.source.x; })
         .attr("y1", function(d){ return d.source.y; })
         .attr("x2", function(d){ return d.target.x; })
         .attr("y2", function(d){ return d.target.y; });
    nodes.attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
         .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; });
    label.attr("x", function(d){ return d.x; })
         .attr("y", function (d) {return d.y - 10; });


});
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7pvhxfzg/32/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force layout's `linkDistance()` can take a function as its argument, in which case it calls that function per link, passing in the link in question (see [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Force-Layout.md#linkDistance)). So you can get the distance right from there:

```
.linkDistance(function(link) { return link.distance })
```